# jQuery script doesn't work after the same HTML has been loaded via AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, event-handling

#### Before you Flag my question as duplicate,

I've Tried solutions provided by existing problems that relates to my problem but unfortunately none of them worked. So here is my problem. I have a fragment that looks like something like this:
`<input type='text' class='input-mini' name='library_fee' readonly/>`
Now  there is a button that executes a query via **AJAX** which returns a new html that is something like this:
`echo "<input type='text' class='input-mini' name='library_fee' value='". $fee['library_fee'] ."' readonly/>"`. It would then return a new HTML with a value property containing the value from the database. It would now fill up the textbox that was once empty.

#### Note: My Query and My AJAX works perfectly fine and doesn't have any problem

---

## PROBLEM

I have a script which has a function that whenever you click the textbox it **removes the readonly** property.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input:text').on('click', function()
    {
        if($(this).is('[readonly]'))
        {
            $(this).removeProp('readonly');
        }
    });
});
```

### THIS WORKS FINE UNTIL THE PAGE IS RELOADED VIA AJAX. WHY?

Comment: I think you have misplaced this jQuery function. It might be overwritten by ajax response.

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using delegation is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(this).on('click','input:text', function()
    {
        if($(this).is('[readonly]'))
        {
            $(this).removeProp('readonly');
        }
    });
});
```

Here `$(this)` refers to document, as delegate target you should use instead closest common static container if any.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `input` is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', ':text', function(event) {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you're replacing an input field with another loaded from the server via AJAX.

Understand, that the jQuery event binding only happens ONCE when $(document).ready() is fired. Unless this event is fired again, when you replace the input, the event is not bound to the new input.

Binding it manually when it has been loaded from the AJAX response is probably the way to go here.

Comment: Sir what possibly would be the answer to this?